# Add an existing xcdatamodeld "folder" to XCode

Tags: xcode, core-data

Does anyone know how to add an existing xcdatamodeld folder to an XCode project? xcdatamodeld is actually a folder, even though the OS recognizes it as a file, much like a [namehere].app folder. When I try to add the xcdatamodeld into XCode, all I get is a folder group with the name of the xcdatamodeld folder; that looks as it should (it uses the special xcdatamodeld icon instead of a folder icon), but when I click the down arrow next to the name, none of the folder contents were brought with the folder. Since the OS recognizes the scdatamodeld as a file, I can't add the folder contents into XCode manually, either.

Any suggestions? I've tried google with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, a right-click on the xcdatamodeld folder, and then "Show Package Contents" brought up the folder contents in the finder. Then it was as simple as drag and drop into xcode! Still, it was a bit of a mystery for a while there.